# Asp.Net Html sanitization library adding line feed after 256 characters

Tags: asp.net, newline, sanitization

The result from

```
Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nunc tellus, consectetur eget blandit euismod, pharetra a libero. In pretium, sem sed mollis hendrerit, libero metus condimentum tellus, eget adipiscing odio ligula at velit. Nulla luctus nisl quis sem venenatis ut suscipit mauris posuere.")
```

will add a line feed at the first space after 256 characters, so "quis sem venenatis ut suscipit mauris posuere." will be on it's own row.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to correct or avoid this?

Regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this was really simple, we just replace existing newlines with a marker string, do the sanitation, remove all newlines that have appeared and put the pre-existing newlines back.

```
    static string newlinemarker = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public static string Sanitize(string html)
    {
        //Change newlines to marker strings
        string escapedHtml = html.Replace(Environment.NewLine, newlinemarker);
        string sanitized = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(escapedHtml);
        //Text should not contain newlines so if the sanitizer has added any they can be removed
        sanitized = sanitized.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
        //Put newline back
        sanitized = sanitized.Replace(newlinemarker, Environment.NewLine);
        return sanitized;
    }
```

Regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the source code, it appears there is a "feature" called `autoNewLines` that is internal to the `HtmlWriter` class that is responsible for generating these newlines.  It is impossible to change that behavior without acquiring a source build copy of the AntiXSS library and building your own version where `autoNewLines` is set to false.

This is probably intended to improve the efficiency for parsing the output HTML in a browser, and the newline in the source should have no effect on the rendering of the output, since browsers generally ignore whitespace.  If parsing the source text without newlines is that critically important, you are probably using the wrong tool for the job.

There is actually an issue related to this in the issue tracker (see specifically the comment by `erwin118`, which addresses your issue): http://wpl.codeplex.com/workitem/15451

Comment: _If parsing the source text without newlines is that critically important, you are probably using the wrong tool for the job._ I must object - a common scenario is to have in-data _with_ newlines and you want to preserve them after the sanitization. Having this lib add more newlines without the option to disable it is just bad design. The method name "GetSafeHtmlFragment" should not do more than make the _fragment safe_.